# What gauge strings should I use for A# tuning on an electric guitar

Tags: guitar, strings, alternative-tunings

I play heavy metal songs from bands such as Parkway Drive, Bring me the Horizon, Northlane etc. which play in A# guitar tuning.

What gauge strings are appropriate for that?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "A# tuning". What are the pitches of each string?

Comment: Drop A#, maybe?

Comment: The general answer for any tuning is here :http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7877/how-do-i-use-string-gauge-tables so the question is effectively a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with Slim - that is an excellent answer

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to experiment. I've never heard anyone play in A#/Bb as that is a tritone off standard tuning... that is, unless it is a baritone guitar OR 7 string, in which case you are just going a tone lower.

The general idea is this: As you lower the pitch you must use fatter strings.

You could get a 7-string pack of strings and use the lower 6 strings on a standard guitar and detune half a step down and this will get you in a Bb tuning.